# WPF CanExecute Constantly Requerying

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a property `IEnumerable<MyObject> MyObjects` in a ViewModel.  I want a certain command in a second view model (that references the first) to be executable when `MyObjects` is populated with at least one object, but not executable when it's empty.

My CanExecute method looks something like this:

```
private bool CanExecute()
{
    return this.viewModel.MyObjects.Any();
}
```

I have a PropertyChanged event that is raised whenever the underlying value of `MyObjects` is changed.

The logic works correctly, however the CanExecute() method is constantly being called-- so much that it basically freezes the entire application.  At the same time, MyObjects is not changing (nor am I raising the PropertyChanged event for it).  Any ideas how I can stop the CanExecute from being re-queried constantly?

Comment: You should probably find the source of the unnecessary events then.

Comment: Depending on what control you have the command bound to, it will execute when certain events tell it to check CanExecute. I believe it has to do with CommandManager.RequerySuggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your command either inherits [RoutedCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand.aspx), or it implements `CanExecuteChanged` like this:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged {
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}
```

Which means adding a handler to your command's `CanExecuteChanged` (which WPF does, to decide when to call your `CanExecute`) is equivalent to adding it to `CommandManager.RequerySuggested`, which is raised very often and as far as I know there is no way to force it to be raised less often.

There's 2 ways around the problem:

1. Don't use `RequerySuggested` at all, just make `CanExecuteChanged` a standard event and raise it specifically when you want it checked.
2. Make sure the `CanExecute` method is very fast so it doesn't matter how often it runs. You could write it as `return this.viewModel.HasAnyObjects;`, where `HasAnyObjects` is a simple field that is set to true or false when `MyObjects` changes.

Comment: Thanks.  I was implementing CanExecuteChanged as you suspected.  Opted for option #2 right now and it cleared up the issue.